# UITextView with attributed text in iOS 6.1 with base SDK iOS 6.1 doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview, ios7, nsattributedstring

My App uses deployment target 5.0, Base SDK 6.1, XCode 5 and runs on a device with iOS 7. I have a `UITextView` with Attributed text in my Storyboard (edited the attributed text in the Storyboard).

My problem is that I only see the attributed text when I build with base SDK 7.0. On 6.1 or 6.0 (in the simulator) I do not see the attributed text, while it should be supported from 6.0+ (before iOS 7 and XCode 5, it worked). I get the warnings on my storyboard (correctly) that "Attributed Text on iOS versions prior to 6.0", but this shouldn't keep iOS 6.0 from displaying Attributed text, right?

Screenshot: [image: Some clarification]

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Everything still builds the same its just a new warning that appears in Xcode 5. Presumably the previous compiler in Xcode 4 couldn't or didn't try to detect this issue.

I use `Latest iOS (iOS 7.0)` for my app's Base SDK with a deployment target of 5.1, and everything builds fine from iOS 5 and up.

Comment: Hmm, any idea why my `UITextView` showed attributed text in previous iOS versions 6.0 and above, but now I build for iOS 7.0, it won't display attributed text (only plain) on iOS versions 6.x? That's my question

Comment: Most likely an issue with the way Xcode 5 compiles nibs (if you're using them). I know they changed the source to something more human-readable in Xcode 5. I've had 50 different issues pop up after updating, even though I used the same exact source code. If you're making it programmatically, I don't know why, but changing the Base SDK should help? http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/07/xcode-5-finally-makes-interface-builder-a-viable-option-for-teams/

Comment: Well, I am using nibs & storyboards, but only the storyboard has a UITextView with attributed text. Changing the base SDK didn't help though :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Probably worth submitting a bug report to Apple. I've had a few issues crop up with Xcode 5. As a temporary work around, it does still working as expected if you set it programmatically, but that can be quite a tedious process.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for letting me know it isn't just me that is experiencing this. Will report the bug to Apple.